# share OpenGL context between multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I'm working on an OpenGL project where there are many scenes. I have successfully implemented the functionality of switching scenes at runtime, so the user can change to another scene by choosing a scene name through the ImGui menu. When that happens, the current scene is deleted to clean up dirty OpenGL internal states, then the new scene will be loaded from a factory pattern. Everything works fine, except that the window will freeze for a few seconds during the transition because unloading/loading scenes takes quite a while to finish.

What I want to do now is to create a loading screen, which will be displayed in between. The task of unloading/loading scenes is scheduled asynchronously using `std::async` and `std::future`, so that the caller is non-blocking and my loading screen can show up. However, since I'm creating the new scene in background in another thread, that thread cannot see the OpenGL context in the main thread, as a result, any `glxxxx()` calls would cause access violation so the new scene cannot be created.

I know that OpenGL is a global state machine which does not support multithreading quite well. I've also read somewhere that it is driver-dependent. Most threads on this topic is old, I wonder if it is still difficult to use multithreading in OpenGL as of 2021. From what I see, loading screen and switching scenes are just very basic functionalities, many applications are able to do so, and I believe there're a bunch of them using OpenGL, why is this problem still not commonly addressed today?

Does anyone know of any external libraries in this regard? Or is there another workaround without using multiple threads?

Comment: [A context's objects can be shared with other contexts](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). This means that you can create 2 OpenGL contexts  (one for the main thread and on for the loading thread) and share one context.

Comment: See [glfw/examples/sharing.c](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/examples/sharing.c)